# Angular jS Multiple Checkbox dropdown filter

Tags: angularjs

I have a Multiple Checkbox Dropdown. I want to make it as a Filter.
So, That if I check one or more boxes it should display data in Table accordingly.

How can I map this Multiple checkbox dropdown with a Table.
Kindly share an example.
Thanks In advance

Comment: first of all should dropdown checkbox and table be in same scope,sorry i don't have a jsfiddle to add code

Comment: @Wa'elJazmaty can you just comment here angular part of it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use $watch in angularjs like

```
$scope.$watch('chkFilterData', function () {
        filterDataToTable();
    });
```

where `chkFilterData` is the data for Multiple Checkbox Dropdown